# What does "coming through in the clutch" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Darry wants to find what happening in the pipeline, so he took sister Trisha's help by holding his legs to see what's happening in the pipeline. Some rats suddenly start coming at them, so she drops him and he falls into the pipeline.

> Trisha: There were rats coming at my face.
>
> Darry: They were running at me too, Trish.
>
> Trisha: I feel really bad. Are you okay?
>
> Darry: Thank you so much, by the way.Thank you for this. Trisha Jenner,
>   **coming through in the clutch**.

Can someone explain the highlighted phrase?

Comment: Please wait at least a day before accepting an answer. See [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700) for more information.

Comment: I'm a native AmE speaker, and the quotation doesn't make sense to me. It sounds like Trisha failed "in the clutch". When the "chips were down", she "dropped the ball", or rather, she dropped Darry. Where is this passage from? Maybe more context would help clarify the intended meaning—or if it's a mistake.

Comment: @BenKovitz I read it as a sarcastic or ironic comment.

Comment: @Hellion Ah, good idea. If that's correct, it should go in an answer.

Comment: @BenKovitz as I mentioned in a comment on my own answer below, I wasn't sure enough to say it was definitively sarcastic, as I could see a scenario in which it wasn't. Given that others have agreed, I have added a clarification to my answer.

Comment: @Cantalouping Just to be clear, I'm not trying to suggest that your answer is wrong. It might be perfect. It's just generally wise to allow a day or two for commenters and competing answers to sort it out. Almost any seemingly good answer (and yours looks good!) can trigger unexpected observations and insights.

Comment: @BenKovitz I agree in that it shouldn't have been accepted so soon; I was just leaning towards the sarcastic intent but I didn't want to put it in without being sure. Sarcasm's the kinda thing that can cause a lot of confusion if you're wrong on your interpretation.

Comment: @Cantalouping It sure is! Good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two components to this phrase to break down.

**[come through](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+through)**:

> 1. [for someone] to do what one is expected to do, especially under difficult conditions

With regards to **in the clutch**, we have to look at the definition of *clutch*. In this context, Darry is using it in the same way it is often used in [sports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clutch_(sports)). In sports it is often used to describe players who can make the best plays even when the pressure is highest. For a person to be good *in the clutch* means to be able to perform in those critical moments, regardless of the pressure or stakes riding on the outcome of the game or match they're participating in.

So just taking **in the clutch** on its own, it means those moments where the stakes and the pressure are at their highest.

Combining these two definitions, to be **coming through in the clutch** means that Trisha has followed through and helped Darry, right when he needed it most.

However, before Darry says this, Trisha drops him when they're confronted by rats. This is the opposite of being clutch, so Darry is likely being sarcastic in his comment, saying that Trisha [choked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(sports)) under pressure.

Comment: It's clear from context, however, that she didn't actually help him when he needed it, she dropped him as soon as they were in trouble.  So I would have to say that Darry is using the phrase ironically or sarcastically.

Comment: I did consider that, but without further context I wasn't willing to claim it was sarcastic or ironic. Given that a few other people seem to agree it was, I will add it to my answer.